# Change id with jquery: Why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I use this code to change id to an `<input type="button" id="avvia_timer" value="AVVIA" />`:

```
$("#avvia_timer").click(function() {
    $(this).val("INIZIA");
    $(this).attr("id", "inizia_timer");
});
```

I changed id with `$(this).attr("id", "inizia_timer");`
Then I want to show 'id' with an alert but doing click on the element with the new id

```
$("#inizia_timer").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

this doesn't work. Why? How can I fix?

Html code:

```
<div id="timer">
    <input type="button" id="avvia_timer" value="AVVIA" />
    <input type="button" id="stop_timer" value="FERMA" />
    <span id="tempo_timer">Timer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what is coming in alert box?

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler as you bound the event to `#inizia_timer` on load, before the element existed. See the question I marked as duplicate for the solution. Also note that changing `id` attributes dynamically is not a very good idea. You should keep `id` static and add/remove classes instead.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: The alert doesn't work @nmnsud

Comment: I edited the question @guest271314

Comment: use `$("#inizia_timer").click(function() {alert($(this).attr("id"));});` inside the first `click` event after `$(this).attr("id", "inizia_timer");`

Comment: I know but then I need of an other function: `$("#inizia_timer").click(function() {` @nmnsud

Comment: @Fabio97 _"I know but then I need of an other function: `$("#inizia_timer").click(function() {`"_ `inizia_timer` would not exist in `document` until `#avvia_timer` is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `click` event to element having new `id` following changing `id`

```js
$("#avvia_timer").click(function() {
    $(this).val("INIZIA")
    .attr("id", "inizia_timer")
    .on("click", function() {
      alert(this.id)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">
    <input type="button" id="avvia_timer" value="AVVIA" />
    <input type="button" id="stop_timer" value="FERMA" />
    <span id="tempo_timer">Timer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function on line ` .on("click", function() {`

Comment: @Fabio97 Is jQuery defined? Is `javascript` at Answer within `.ready()` handler?

Comment: Yes it is @guest271314

Comment: @Fabio97 Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: Later I need to use this new id `$("#inizia_timer").click(function() {`

Comment: @Fabio97 You can use the pattern at Answer, that is, attach `.click(handler)` chained to `.attr("id", "newId")`, or approaches described at duplicate Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements . `$("#inizia_timer")` would not be defined before click of original element as element having `id` `inizia_timer` would not exist in `document`. You can attach event to element when element is created, as demonstrated at Answer; or, attach event to element parent element. See https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/